# using Router in express-4

Tags: node.js, express

i am trying to execute below code after upgrading express4

```
// call the Router
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/test1', function(req, res, next) {

// doing more stuff
res.send('test test1 route')
});

// call our router we just created
app.use('/dogs', dogs);
```

but for some reason i am getting following error

```
this._router = new Router({
               ^
TypeError: object is not a function
at Function.app.lazyrouter
```

can someone help me to solve this problem ,Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use this approach for routing in express4, when i am upgrading to express4 i didn't deleted express 3 folder, i tried deleting express3 folder from node modules and installing express4 than this worked fine

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

```
var app = express();

app.route('/events')
.all(function(req, res, next) {
  // runs for all HTTP verbs first
  // think of it as route specific middleware!
})
.get(function(req, res, next) {
  res.json(...);
})
.post(function(req, res, next) {
  // maybe add a new event...
})
```

So try:

```
var router = app.route();

router.get('......
```

Or check the 3 to 4 [upgrade guide](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x).

Which says:

> app.router has been removed and middleware and routes are executed in
>   the order they are added. Your code should move any calls to app.use
>   that came after app.use(app.router) after any routes (HTTP verbs).

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser());
/// .. other middleware .. doesn't matter what

app.get('/' ...);
app.post(...);

// more middleware (executes after routes)
app.use(function(req, res, next);
// error handling middleware
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {});
```

Comment: thanks for u r reply majidarif, above code also works according to the new router. i upgraded to express 4 with out deleting express3, now i deleted the express folder and installed again and it worked!

Comment: So, in `express 4` the `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` (use of static folder) must come after all declared `routes`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a reputation to comment. Where and how did you declare your `dog`? Did you mean the following?:

```
// call the Router
var router = express.Router();

// call our router we just created
app.use(router);

router.get('/test1', function(req, res, next) {

    // doing more stuff
    res.send('test test1 route')
});
```